# AVPlayer seekToTime only generates frame every second

Tags: ios, video, frame, avplayer, avplayerlayer

how can I make `AVPlayerLayer` display the exact video's frame in method `seekToTime`.

Now `[AVPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(A, B))]`, the `AVPlayerLayer` only displays the frame at every 1-second change for example 1.50-2.50-3.50. I want it to display frame at 4.45 second for example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [[AVPlayer seekToTime: toleranceBefore: toleranceAfter:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime%3atoleranceBefore%3atoleranceAfter%3a) to get random media access with higher precision.
To get the highest precision possible, pass `kCMTimeZero` as argument for both tolerances. Note that this might add noticeable delay during seeks.

Comment: There is no delay for forward video but backward. How do I prevent it?

Comment: You can't. The higher precision requires more compositing operations. The seekToTime: methods also provide variants that take a completion handler. You could use a completion handler based seek to make your app more responsive. Those methods also have the advantage that the previous seek request gets canceled. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:completionHandler:

Comment: Yes !! Do you have any idea how Instagram and built in Photo app do the video rewind so smooth.

Comment: @TungVo did you ever figure it out?